# Not able to cross-fade images correctly using jQuery and CSS3?

Tags: jquery, css, image-gallery

I have an image gallery:

[image]

My plan is that when I click on of the smaller images, it will fade in on top of the large image.
([see my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46JQS/1/))

I want to achieve this using CSS3 `transition: opacity 0.8s ease;`.

I could use

```
$(img).appendTo($('.inner-container')).hide().fadeIn()
```

But that didn't work so well either.

My code:

```
$('.slides-container img').on('click', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    var currentImg = $('.inner-container img');
    var img = $('<img/>').attr({
        src: url,
        class: '',
        alt: '',
        title: ''
    });

    /*
    $(img).appendTo($('.inner-container')).hide().fadeIn(800, function(){
        $(currentImg).remove();
    });
    */

    $(img).appendTo($('.inner-container')).removeClass('hide').promise().done(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(currentImg).remove();
        }, 800);
    });

});
```

What am I missing in order to get a smooth fade in?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I already have. Se my Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix this:

```
$(img).appendTo...
```

to this:

```
img.appendTo...
```

since it's already declared as a jQuery element.

See it work, the JS way: http://jsfiddle.net/46JQS/3/

Note that I also had to remove the CSS transitions so they don't clash with each other.

---

And here is the CSS version. For some reason, I also had to add a little timeout before removing the `hide` class and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/46JQS/6/. I believe it's because the class was removed before the element rendered in the DOM, so the CSS transitions never fired.

I've also removed the promise.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle where jquery u described works.

```
$('.click').on('click',function(){
    var img = $(this).find('img').clone().hide();
    var mainContainer = $('.main_container');
    mainContainer.append(img);
    img.fadeIn(800,function(){
        mainContainer.find('img:eq(0)').remove();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C9G84/1/